# MYSQL query sum total but different column values

Tags: mysql

I've a table of orders, like this:

```
subject  | Price | Percentage 
order#1  |  0,2  |   50    | 
order#2  |  0,6  |   25    | 
order#3. |  5    |   x?    | 
etc..#999
```

I would like to sum all the rows with the same percentage and then sum all the other that have the same percentage until all are summed.

How could I accomplish this with mysql or php?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem.

```
SELECT Percentage, SUM(Price) AS Total
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Percentage;
```

You should get a result like this:

| Percentage | Total |

|  50 |   13.5    |

|  25  |   25.2    |

...

Hope I understood it correctly...